# Resize all components in layeredPane at once retaining relative position and size

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, resize, jlayeredpane

I have made a GUI using `Swing` and `layeredPanes`, specifying dimensions and (x,y) co-ordinates of about 60 items. The `JFrame` dimensions I set are (1080, 720) but I need now to rescale the whole lot to fit (800, 600).

Is there a quick way of resizing the whole screen so all images and text retain their position and relative size without going through every component and re-specifying its `setBounds(x, y, width, height)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a ComponentListener to your JLayeredPane, and then in the

`void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)`

you could rescale everything based on the current height and width to maintain a specific ratio. You could just do some math some simple math to get the difference ratio between say, 720 and your current width, then adjust the width of each of your components to their actual width times this ratio.

Then do the same for height. This way everything would maintain aspect ratio.

I would also store each component in a List to access them more easily.

EDIT: I just re-read your question:

> without going through every component and re-specifying

I forgot about this while answering, and I don't think there is a simple way of doing it without going through all of them. But there are simple ways of looping through them tho!

Comment: must be delayed by Swing Timer, because ComponentListener firing an event per each of pixels

Comment: Thanks, a for loop would be great except I don't add all the components in the same method, there are about 20 methods for displaying a group of different types of component, I would have to have a loop in each method right?

Comment: When you create those components, you could push them into a collection, then later when resizing is required loop through that collection.